# Orthonormal Basis of Multi-Dimensional Sobolev Space of Different Orders without Reproducing Kernel

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces, approximation-theory

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Under regularity conditions, we know that the $s$-th order Sobolev space $H^s(\Omega)$ with $s \geq d/2$ is a reproducing kernel Hilbert space. In contrast, $H^s(\Omega)$ with $s < d/2$ is only a Hilbert space without the reproducing property.

My question is about the construction of orthonormal basis of $H^s(\Omega)$.

For $s \geq d/2$, the eigenfunction of the reproducing kernel gives us an orthonormal basis, which up to a rescaling of magnitudes is also an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\Omega)$ (which can be equivalently written as $H^0(\Omega)$).

For $s < d/2$, how do we construct an orthonormal basis in a similar fashion, given now there is no reproducing kernel? **Moreover, for $0 \leq s_1, s_2 < d/2$, is it possible to align the orthonormal bases of $H^{s_1}(\Omega)$ and $H^{s_2}(\Omega)$ so that they only differ up to a rescaling of magnitudes?**

Comment: I believe that this is not a meaningful question. You see, even though $H^s(\Omega)$ is called a Hilbert space  it is technically not, in the sense that the actual Hilbert norm on it is not fixed. It is a sort of infinite dimensional analog of a linear space   of finite dimension:  you are free  to chose   any of the (equivalent)  scalar products.  Naturally, an orthonormal basis would very much depend on the choice.

Comment: @AlexGavrilov I totally agree with you on that the norm and inner product are not unique. We are interested in the "natural" choice of Sobolev norm and inner product $<u, v> = \sum_{i=1}^k \langle D^i u, D^i v \rangle$, especially how to construct the corresponding basis, for example, the eigenvector of the reproducing kernel. Also, for $0 \leq s_1, s_2 < d/2$, is it possible to align the orthonormal bases of $H^{s_1}(\Omega)$ and $H^{s_2}(\Omega)$ so that they only differ up to a rescaling of magnitudes?

Comment: Even  this is not so ``natural'' a choice. What is the  big reason to take all of this terms with  weight one?  (It is not  invariant with respect to scaling, for example.)  I admit  that in this case the question actually has an answer,  but I  also admit that, personally, I totally  would  not care about it.